# How to pass JWT token through header in react native to django rest api?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, react-native

I'm passing token(already i known from console) in header as in below code and want data from that localhost after that user get authenticated but on my android emulator it showing error `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`

Login.js

```
componentDidMount() {
     return fetch('http://10.42.0.1:8000/stocks/',
        {
         method: "GET",
         headers: 
         {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhbSIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjYxLCJlbWFpbCI6IiIsImV4cCI6MTUwMzk0ODYyMH0.l4VLMLXcSZ7nOmKmjblLKFr0lTSpgYeFks_JeYiO7cU"}`
         }
  })

     ...

  }
```

In views.py

```
class Stocks(APIView):
      permissions_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
      authentication_classes= (TokenAuthentication,)
      def get(self,request):
          stocks=stock.objects.all()
          serailizer=serial(stocks,many=True)
          return Response(serailizer.data)
```

here the token is not reaching at the server and hence permission is not granted.
we are using Django rest jwt token.
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token format has been changed, now you need to send "JWT {token}" See the [docs](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#usage).

Then i recommend [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to 'organize' your server communication.

And the solution be like:

```
return axios({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `url`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `JWT ${token}`,
  },
  data: dataToSend,
});
```